# Import Existing ZK Project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, zk

I am new to using ZK Framework for Web application development. I want to import ZK Project into Eclipse with this steps :

```
1. From the main menu, select command File > Import.... The Import wizard opens.
2. Select General > Existing Project into Workspace and click Next.
3. Choose either Select root directory or Select archive file and click the associated Browse... to locate the directory or file containing the projects.
4. Under Projects, select the project or projects which I would like to import.
5. Click Finish to start the import.
```

Yes, it works, but my ZK Project have lots of error lines, because it does not recognize ZK APIs.

I think it happened because my ZK Project was recognized as Java Project, not as ZK Project. So this Project does not include ZK library in its classpath.

I also had tried the following steps to import my ZK Project:

```
1. File -> Import, 
2. Expand ZK folder -> Click Import ZK Archive
3. Click "Directory Import" button to find my ZK Project directory
4. Finish
```

But it does not work. Error message : *The Archive that your try to import is not acceptable*

Answer (score 0):

ZK Studio plugin will not automatically recognize the ZK Library inside an existing ZK Project and associate it with the correct ZK library version. This will happen if the existing ZK Project was not created with ZK Studio support. You can re-associate the ZK Library by the following steps.

1. Project -> Properties
2. ZK -> Package Setting
3. Select an existing ZK Package from the dropdown list
4. Click re-associate source's jar files

To change from Java project to ZK project, you may need to add the following lines to .project file located in the project root.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    ...
    <natures>
         <nature>org.zkoss.eclipse.zknature</nature>
         ...
    </nature>
    ...
</projectDescription>`

You are also trying to import a ZK Project as a ZK Package. ZK Archive refers to the ZK Library zip files such as the ones downloaded from www.zkoss.org/download/zk.